# Caused by: android.view.InflateException Error inflating class in Android app

Tags: java, android, inflate-exception

I've been developing an app for a week now and everything was going fine. I wasn't having any troubles with any of the 3 devices in which I test the Apps I develope. But now I just runned the app on one of these three devices and everything went to hell. The weirdest thing is that the app works perfectly on the other two devices but on the third one it crashes on the first onCreate() call. I sincerely don't know what am I doing wrong that it's not working on one of my devices. Here's my code.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myapp.miquel.mqlapps.hombresmujeresapp">

    <meta-data
        android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"
        android:value="here_goes_my_real_admob_id" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ndroid.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ResultActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GenderChoiceActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about_app"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MQLAppsIniActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MenuActivity.java** (here is where the exception is being thrown **on the setContentView() call** inside the onCreate() method). For your information, in this class I just handle three buttons, and depending on what the user clicks, it starts one Activity or another.

```
package myapp.miquel.mqlapps.hombresmujeresapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String gender = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        Typeface tf_existence = Typeface.createFromAsset(MenuActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "Existence-Light.otf");

        Button initTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.initTest);
        initTest.setTypeface(tf_existence);

        Button ajustes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ajustes);
        ajustes.setTypeface(tf_existence);

        Button sobreLaApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sobreApp);
        sobreLaApp.setTypeface(tf_existence);



        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            gender = extras.getString("GENERO");
        }



        initTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(final View v) {

                MenuActivity.this.finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("GENERO", gender);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ajustes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(final View v) {

                //MenuActivity.this.finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("GENERO", gender);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        sobreLaApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(final View v) {

                //MenuActivity.this.finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, AboutAppActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // put your code here...


    }

}
```

**activity_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="myapp.miquel.mqlapps.hombresmujeresapp.ResultActivity"
    android:background="#bbdefb">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            style="@style/ButtonInitTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:text="Iniciar test"
            android:id="@+id/initTest"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            style="@style/ButtonSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:text="Ajustes"
            android:id="@+id/ajustes"
            android:layout_below="@+id/initTest"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            style="@style/ButtonAbout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:text="Sobre la App"
            android:id="@+id/sobreApp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ajustes"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you may notice, I'm using a custom style for those buttons. The style is:

```
<style name="ButtonNormalText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor" >@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize" >25dip</item>
        <item name="android:height" >44dip</item>
        <item name="android:background" >@drawable/default_button</item>
        <item name="android:focusable" >true</item>
        <item name="android:clickable" >true</item>
    </style>

<style name="ButtonInitTest" parent="ButtonNormalText">
        <item name="android:drawableLeft" >@drawable/test_icon</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonSettings" parent="ButtonNormalText">
        <item name="android:drawableLeft" >@drawable/ic_settings</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonAbout" parent="ButtonNormalText">
        <item name="android:drawableLeft" >@drawable/ic_about</item>
    </style>
```

And finally this is the LogCat error. Since it's pretty long I'll write just the Caused by:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: myapp.miquel.mqlapps.hombresmujeresapp, PID: 13239
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp.miquel.mqlapps.hombresmujeresapp/myapp.miquel.mqlapps.hombresmujeresapp.MenuActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: <internal>: <nine-patch> requires a valid 9-patch source image
```

Everything is happening at:

```
at myapp.miquel.mqlapps.hombresmujeresapp.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:30)
```

Which is the **setContentView() call** from the **onCreate()** in **MenuActivity**

I'd be very pleased if you could please take the time to check my code and let me know if I'm doing something wrong. This is so far the weirdest trouble I've been facing for a long time. Thanks in advance!

Well, people it seems that I'm having troubles with a 9-patch source image that I don't even have. All of my drawables are .xml or .png files but not .9.png at all. This is so weird.

Comment: Apparently one of your drawable isn't a correct 9-patch image :
"requires a valid 9-patch source image"

Comment: I noticed that, but what does that mean? What's a 9-patch source image?

Comment: a 9-patch image is a extensible image. You can find some documentation here :
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/draw9patch.html
Look in your drawable an image with the extension ".9.png"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Anyway it's weird because I removed any drawable call from the .xml and the error keeps being thrown.

Comment: And I also don't have any drawable with the extensin ".9.png" or at least I'm not seeing this extension

Answer (score 0):

Well, people it seems that I'm having troubles with a 9-patch source image that I don't even have. All of my drawables are .xml. The problem is getting surreal. I've even removed all of the widgets from the .xml file and the error keeps being thrown. Don't know what's going wrong.